# Install package by file provided in yum/dnf

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, texlive

At least on a recent Fedora system, it is possible to install a TeXLive package by specifying a .sty file, which is great, as in

```
yum install 'tex(amsmath.sty)'
```

It also work with `dnf`, the soon to be replacement for yum. I can't find any documentation about how that's supposed to work, apart from 'you can do it', both `yum` and `dnf` manpages have no mention of this.

Is this using some more general feature or that specific to TeXLive packages? It doesn't seem to be related to the `provide` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already seem to have guessed, it works via the provides mechanism - the `texlive-amsmath` package has a provide for `tex(amsmath.sty)` as you can see by asking rpm:

```
% rpm -q --provides texlive-amsmath
tex(amsbsy.sty) = 2013
tex(amscd.sty) = 2013
tex(amsgen.sty) = 2013
tex(amsmath.sty) = 2013
tex(amsopn.sty) = 2013
tex(amstex.sty) = 2013
tex(amstext.sty) = 2013
tex(amsxtra.sty) = 2013
tex-amsmath = 2013
texlive-amsmath = 3:svn30645.2.14-4.fc20
```

There may not be an explicit `Provide` tag in the spec file though, as the provides might be generated automatically by a script.

Comment: I see, do you know if there is any convention to name those?

Comment: Well as I say they are quite likely generated automatically by a script in line with the relevant packaging guidelines.